# How to make the Fourier Descriptor result to be Insensitive?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, shapes, fourier-descriptors

I am trying to distinguish shape for images in Matlab by using the Fourier Descriptor. What I want to do is : 1. Generate the Fourier Descriptors for each image; 2. Calculate the Euclidian Distance between these Fourier Descriptors to compare the shapes.

My problem is I cannot make the result of calculating the Fourier Descriptor to be insensitive for the geometric transformation (e.g. Rotation & Scaling).

The code I use now is the "Gonzales matlab version", the one in this [link](http://www.codeforge.com/read/84870/frdescp.m__html). I have tried to normalize the result by doing this:

```
% Normalization
DC = f(1);
f = f(2:11); % getting the first 20 & deleting the dc component
f = abs(f) ; % use magnitudes to be invariant to translation & rotation
f = f/DC; % devide the fourier coeffients by the DC-coefficient to be invariant to scale
```

But I don't think it worked as I expected. The result is different if I change the direction or the scale of a same image.

I have been trapped by this question for a couple of days. I will appreciate any suggestion, thank you all in advance!

Comment: Note that Fourier transform preserves euclidean distance...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by saying "Fourier transform preserves euclidean distance"? Does this issue lead to my error?

Comment: You say that you're trying to calculate Euclidean distance in the Fourier domain.  What I'm saying is that this value will be the same in the un-transformed domain.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh, I see what you mean. Actually, I just need to implement the Fourier Descriptor to describe the Shape in the image which involves the fft. If you think there are any better method to compare the shape, please feel free to tell me. Thanks you very much. :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read 
"Feauture Extraction and Image Processing for Computer Vision"
by Nixon and Aguado. 
You will find there what you are looking for